# Can I define a Clojure protocol with methods starting with ":"?

Tags: clojure

I would like to provide some methods for a clojure protocol starting with the : character. Is there any way to override this in Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think so. Clojure keywords are implemented in the reader and I don't think there's any way of overriding that behavior.

When you use a keyword as a function, that is equivalent to (get arg :keyword). You *can* extend what that does by implementing ILookup in your protocol.

Joost.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bad idea: colons are reserved for keywords so even if you could do this I think it would make for some confusing code.

You can of course, put a function inside a record mapped by a keyword:

```
(defrecord Foo [])

(def foo (Foo. nil {:method (fn [a b] (* a b))}))

((:method foo) 7 10)
=> 70
```

I've found this to be a useful trick sometimes......